# List name to String in Mathematica

Tags: string, wolfram-mathematica, expression

Considering :

```
 daList=Range[10]
```

What I need is the title to be the list name but trying :

```
ListPlot[daList, PlotLabel -> ToString[daList]]
```

does not seem to work.

[image]

**EDIT**

"daList" is the Title I want. **SORRY** for previous my previous lack of precision

**EDIT**

I yet can`t make any solution work but I think I isolated the problem. The list name is a plotting Function argument. I believe the simple version replicating my problem is like :

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
naming[list_] := ToString[HoldForm[list]];
naming[list]
```

an below my "real" code :

```
sequenceCountPlot[conditionSet_] :=
ListPlot[sequenceCountALL[conditionSet],
plotOptions[
("DisplayNo looking outside filter" <> (ToString[HoldForm[conditionSet]])), 
"Number of Display", 
"Filter Radius in Cm", 
 prefCOLORS], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, Max@(Max /@ sequenceCountALL[conditionSet])}}, Joined -> True]
```

Where plotOptions is a function to customize some options (Titles and Colors) and feet the plot with other.
Please know that Even with Evaluate[plotOptions] the results remain the same.

Comment: What do you mean a string Transformation? What is the result that you seek?

Comment: Your edit adds to the confusion. Your first figure already has "daList" as title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
ToString[HoldForm@daList]
```

so eg

```
ListPlot[daList, PlotLabel -> ToString[HoldForm@daList]]
```

[image]

Comment: It does not work in my current setting where I have a plotting function that take the list name (expression) as an input : I think this reflects the problem : list = {1, 2, 3, 4} ; naming[list_] := ToString[HoldForm[list]]; naming[list]; Any thoughts ?

Comment: @500 here: `list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
ClearAll[naming];
SetAttributes[naming, HoldFirst];
naming[list_] := ToString[HoldForm[list]]` ie, add `SetAttributes[naming, HoldFirst]` before defining `naming`

Comment: I am about to give up, it still does not work when it is nested in my plotting function. Can you see obvious reasons why from this syntax ? sequenceCountPlot[conditionSet_] :=
 
 ListPlot[sequenceCountALL[conditionSet],
  plotOptions[("DisplayNo looking outside filter" <> 
     naming[conditionSet]), "Number of Display", 
   "Filter Radius in Cm", prefCOLORS], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 
     Max@(Max /@ sequenceCountALL[conditionSet])}}, Joined -> True]

Comment: @500 Hard to say without knowing what this is supposed to do, but, how about `SetAttribute[sequenceCountPlot,HoldAll]`? I'm guessing what you expect this to do so maybe it won't work, in which case, put some more detail in your question. (note that you should still set this attribute for `naming`, too)

Comment: @500 so to clarify: in this piece of code, `naming` does not see the symbol `conditionSet` at all: it only sees the result of evaluating it, ie, the list (or whatever it contains). Setting the attribute I said for `sequenceCountPlot` means that `naming` will receive the symbol and, if you also set `HoldAll` for `naming`, it will then pass it on to whatever is inside (if you don't, it will evaluate and pass the result on). Roughly, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that two the most convenient ways to do this are:

```
daList = Range[10];
ListPlot[daList, PlotLabel -> "daList"]
ListPlot[daList, PlotLabel -> HoldForm[daList]]
```

Other possibilities:

```
ListPlot[daList, PlotLabel -> MakeBoxes[daList]]
ListPlot[daList, PlotLabel -> SymbolName[Unevaluated@daList]]
ListPlot[daList, PlotLabel -> ToString[Unevaluated@daList]]
ListPlot[daList, PlotLabel -> ToString[HoldForm@daList]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```
ListPlot[daList, PlotLabel -> ToString[Unevaluated[daList]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

may be

```
ListPlot[daList, PlotLabel -> StringJoin[Map[ToString, daList]]]
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the desired output is `daList` (literally) as the title. Maybe I misinterpreted the question though.

Comment: My bad, sorry Nasser. @acl, I fear you`re making excellent inferences based on my previous lack of precision/attention. ;-)

Comment: I understood it as 500 wanting the value of daList as string.